# Elm Html Bool as type variable

Tags: elm

Can Elm Html have Bool type variable so instead of type annotation of

```
Html Msg
```

have

```
Html Bool
```

Does anybody knows? Thanks a lot to all.

Comment: The answer is yes. It can be anything as long as you handle it appropriately in `update`.

Comment: Here's an Ellie demonstrating it: https://ellie-app.com/5yw38K3Qnb7a1

Comment: Of course, the reality is you almost always want a real message type, as it's much more flexible and descriptive. Most of the time your boolean value is going to represent something that is more clearly represented by a custom type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Elm Html uses the type `Html msg` (with a small caps `msg`). This means that `msg` can be whatever type.

In many code examples found online, `msg` is `Msg`. But that is just their choice, and they have defined `Msg` themselves somewhere else in the code.

In your code you can use any other type, like `Bool`.